# How to creating custom links that can be echo'ed individually

Tags: 8, theming

Let's assume I have a footer with this div for which I have created a custom block named as `custom_footer`:

```
{% if page.custom_footer %}
<div class='footer' style='background-image:url('/images/bg.jpg')">

</div>
{% endif %}
```

Now, I would like to put links inside the footer that are created using `Home  > Administration > Structure > Menus > Add menu` in other words I don't want to insert hard-coded menus like `<a href='/services'>services</a>`  inside the footer div.

So, is there anyway to echo all the custom links for page created inside my footer?

Comment: This can be implemented with blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be implemented using blocks.

- First create the required menus from  `Home  > Administration >
  Structure > Menus > Add menu`
- Place the new  menu as a block under footer section in `Home  > Administration > Structure > Block layout`
- Save blocks

Find the reference images:

- Add user account menu to footer block (You can also include your custom menus),

[image: add menu to footer block]

- Image listng user account menu on footer

[image: menu link on footer]

Comment: This does not work. I have created a menu called sitemap gave it it's own url `/sitemap` now in `Home  > Administration > Structure > Block layout` Inside my footer block I can't add that menu